# Where are drivers located for rEFInd?

Tags: kernel, uefi, macosx, ext4

I am planning to recompile my kernel with EFI Stub support, but currently my Ubuntu installation's partition is formatted with ext4fs.

I have the rEFInd ext4fs driver (ext4_x86.efi) in the refind-bin binary package I downloaded, but where should I put that?

I have installed rEFInd from OS X in my `/EFI/refind` directory in Mac OS X (I believe that is the main installation directory for refind, correct?). There is no folder there called `drivers_x86`. Should I create the folder and copy the driver there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a rEFInd installation on the OS X root partition, you should create the `/EFI/refind/drivers_x64` or `/EFI/refind/drivers` directory and place your 64-bit drivers there. (Note that it's `drivers_x64`, not `drivers_x86`. I know that's confusing, but it's the naming convention for EFI -- `ia32` for 32-bit x86 and `x64` for 64-bit x86-64/AMD64.)